# PHP MVC database relationship objects

Tags: php, database, oop, model-view-controller, relationships

I am trying to figure out how to model database relationships in PHP. Say for instance I have a User class and a Book class. A User has many books (one-to-many).

I have seen in frameworks that you can do,

$books = getUser($id)->getBooks();
to retrieve all books that belong to user with $id.

So I thought about doing it in either (i dont want to use frameworks or ORM),
1. get the user first
2. get the books that belong to user
(two SQL queries)
or
1. get all books that belong to the user using a sql join query.

I want this to be generic so it can work for many different scenarios, so say for instance. user has many books, book has many reviews and so on..

Thanks in advance.
john

Answer (score 1):

Doing something generic is called an ORM (like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/introduction.html) for example), it's very hard to build one.

If you want to create yours, an easy way to start is to use [proxy objects](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/263-Proxies-in-PHP.html) to separate your model from database:

```
<?php

class User
{
    protected $id;
    protected $books;

    public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->books;
    }

    public function fromArray(array $data)
    {
        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            $this->id = $data['id'];
        }
    }
}

class Book
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;

    public function fromArray(array $data)
    {
        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            $this->id = $data['id'];
        }
        if (isset($data['name'])) {
            $this->name = $data['name'];
        }
    }
}

class UserProxy extends User
{
    public function getBooks()
    {
        $userId = $this->id;
        $booksArr = // do sql query to fetch books belongs to $userId
        $books = array();
        foreach ($booksArr as $bookArr) {
             $book = new Book();
             $book->fromArray($bookArr);
             $books[] = $book;
        }

        $this->books = $books;
        parent::getBooks();
    }
}
```

**You can improve my example with:**

use a class to manage collections (something like : [Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php))

use Reflection (instead of `fromArray` methods):

- get objects properties with [ReflectionClass::getProperties()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/reflectionclass.getproperties.php).
- set them to true with [ReflectionProperty::setAccessible()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php).
- bind them with [ReflectionProperty::setValue()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/reflectionproperty.setvalue.php).

---

**EDIT:**

here's an example:

```
<?php

$userArr = // fetch your user from database (with an associative array)
$user = new User();
$user->fromArray($userArr);

var_dump($user->getBooks());
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your example? For example how do I use this class? Can you show us an example?